# Normalized Relational Data in NoSQL databases

Tags: nosql, elasticsearch

I'm thinking of using ElasticSearch as a database. I require the following:

1. Hierarchy / Categorization (e.g. Confectionery:Chocolate:Bars),
2. Linking products to the specific category, and also the parent of the category (e.g. if browsing at the 'Confectionary' category, I should see all chocolate bars, all chocolate blocks, lollies etc, but at the Bars category level, I should see only chocolate bars).

What is the approach to be taken in nosql databases, or more specifically in ElasticSearch?

Is there a way in ElasticSearch to normalize and represent relationships - e.g. If I changed the name of a category, I don't want to reindex all the products...

I have also thought about integrating neo4j with elasticsearch - using neo4j as the system of records db, and elasticsearch to index the nodes in neo4j. Does anyone have any thoughts on this approach?

Thanks